# Criar ficheiro xls e guardar numa pasta

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Tenho o meu ficheiro `gerar_xls.php` e está a criar um ficheiro `.xls` e quero guardá-lo numa pasta. O que está a fazer agora é o download do ficheiro. Tenho o seguinte:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=ocorrencias.xls");

echo "escrever no ficheiro xls";
```

O ficheiro está a ser bem criado, mas o que quero é guardar o ficheiro numa pasta dentro do servidor e não fazer o download dele. Existe alguma alteração no `header` que faça isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cabeçalhos HTTP são parte das solicitações HTTP e respostas que são enviados ao se comunicar através de uma rede. Eles detêm informações sobre o cliente, o servidor, a informação a ser enviada e muito mais.

Se um script cria um arquivo e envia para um cliente, o script deve criar os cabeçalhos apropriados para notificar o cliente que o tipo de arquivo é `(Content-type: application / vnd.ms-excel)`, seja para fazer o download diretamente `(Conteúdo -Disposition: attachment)` ou visualizá-lo em um navegador da web, e assim por diante.

Se o script cria um arquivo e salvá-lo para o servidor (por exemplo, usando `file_put_contents ($ nome_do_arquivo, $ dados))`, nenhum cabeçalho precisa ser definido como o arquivo não está sendo enviada através da rede. Se alguém quer, posteriormente, para baixar o arquivo, por exemplo, utilizando um cliente de FTP ou usando outro script, esse script ou programa de FTP no servidor irá definir os cabeçalhos apropriados quando ocorre a transferência.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021162/create-xls-file-and-save-to-a-folder